# Setting "Space" as a Character

Tags: java, android, whitespace

A small question that has been bugging me for a while. I'm making a simple riddle game - it sets you the question, you type the answer and press the button to get to the next level. So, in one of the activities the answer must be "spacebar", and the user must type " ". Problem is, the system doesn't recognize space as a character, so the Next Level button does nothing.

Is there anything I can do about it? I've been playing around with "Character.isSpaceChar" but nothing happens.

**Question Activity.java**

```
 mSayAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SayAnswer);

    mSayAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String answer = mAnswers.getText().toString().trim();
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("")) { //here's the part of the problem

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Stage", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("QuestionEleven", true);
                editor.apply();

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuestionTwelve.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }else {

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: If space might be an answer, so why do you `trim` the string?

Comment: I believe you should check that `mAnswers.getText().toString().equals(" ");`

Comment: Oh... copying the same code for 50 questions really did the damage - I didn't see it there. Thank you guys, that did the trick (the .equals(" ") part was unneeded). I'll post it as an answer for everyone to see.

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, the answer was very simple as well.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        String answer = mAnswers.getText().toString(); //had to get rid of the "trim"
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(" "))
```

Thanks once again for the help.